# Why can't I get my caster wheels to engage their inserts?

Tags: desk

I drilled a hole into 4 desk legs to add caster wheels. Added the metal inserts into which the casters will slide into. I can't manage to push the wheels into the the inserts. For some reason even banging them with a hammer doesn't move them much. Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if we knew something about your hardware. Please post photos or a product link. Chances are, though, that you just need to get rowdy with it. They're probably pretty tight until the retaining ring slips past its detent. Be sure to support the table with the floor so you don't damage it.

Comment: If the insert is C shaped, it may need to expand slightly when the caster is inserted. The hole in the wood may be too small to allow expansion.

Comment: Are you 100% certain you have the correct inserts for the casters you have?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that you drilled the proper size hole?

Comment: Aaron, please take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum and your answer doesn't belong in your question. If you're abandoning the post, please delete it.

Comment: Also, such inserts normally don't need to expand. That wouldn't make much sense in a solid leg. If the insert fit, the hole is fine.

Comment: So what then could be the reason the stem wont enter the insert?

Comment: Here is the item I am using https://www.amazon.com/dp/B008KIST2K?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details